# What is the best way to retrieve cookies from Internet Explorer

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to view cookies from IE using IEGetProtectedModeCookie however all i am getting back is error 1411. I have tried a few different variations with the domain name etc but not having any luck.

```
wchar_t wszCookieData[1024];
char szError[128];
DWORD dwSize = 1024;    
IEGetProtectedModeCookie(L"www.google.com", L"PREF", wszCookieData, &dwSize, 0);
//MessageBox(0, szCookieData, "IE COOKIES", 0);
wsprintf(szError, "Last Error: %d", GetLastError());
MessageBox(0, szError, 0, 0);
```

What is the best way to retrieve cookies from Internet Explorer?

EDIT: Ok i got it working semi now, i had the domain in wrong format, need HTTPS:// prefix. I can view some cookies but i am unable to view session cookies. Anyone know how to view session cookies?

Comment: Is the call actually failing? `GetLastError()` isn't necessarily displaying an error set by `IEGetProtectedModeCookie()` -- it might be from an earlier call. Check the HRESULT.

Comment: Checked HRESULT it is a "Class does not exist" error.